# i am unable to set the logs by date ? How to set bydate in log4j.prop file? i have applied these stuff but are not generating daily

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

This is my log file i want to set the logs by date.Currently i have set the parameter by date and it isn't working.
This is my log4j.prop file .The pattern as of now.
KTAdvisor.log

KTAdvisor.log.2... so on

```
log4j.rootLogger = all, file
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File = ${catalina.base}//logs//KTAdvisor.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize = 10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex = 10
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L
```

I have changed the parameter to-

```
log4j.rootLogger = all, file
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.File = ${catalina.base}//logs//KTAdvisor.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

Comment: "This is my log file" - What file?

Comment: Please EDIT your question and try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is my log4j.properties file and it has the configuration like this..i have tried one solution which is change parameter has in the question.But that configuration doesn't work .Can u tell me how to generate logs daily by having date in the name.Means KTAdvisor-2018-07-29 like this